# How to to confirming before deleting in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have code like this in Page_Load()

```
btnMainDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')){}else{return true}");
```

Basically, it's confirming that before deletion (Yes/No). If it's a yes then delete the record and if it's no then do nothing.

For the btnMainDelete, I put as follow:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMainDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnMainDelete_Click" />
```

Now the issue is that, what I press Yes or No always executes `btnMainDelete_Click` on the server side? I must have something missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Put valid confirm script in the OnClientClick:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMainDelete" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?');" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btnMainDelete_Click" />
```

Comment: +1.  I was about to post the same with only this difference: OnClientClick="javascript:confirm('Are you sure?');"

Comment: That's actually not the issue - the way the OP is adding the javascript is a bit old-school, but it's still accomplishing the same thing as OnClientClick.  The problem is that he's never returning false.

Comment: I think using OnClientClick is cleaner and a better example for others to go by.

Comment: Agree 100%.  But the issue that he's facing is that his javascript is wrong.

Comment: Great, this also solved my problem. But is it possible to change the headertext of the message box? Right now I'm using this code:

    `OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this assignment?');"`

In my ASP code.

Answer (score 7):

You need to fix your script.  In the script as written it is never preventing further execution of the script by returning false.

try:

```
return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
```

IE:

```
btnMainDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');");
```

Comment: Definitely the correct way to do it. or ...OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"... on aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

you want to modify your code with

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMainDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick  ="javascript:confirm('Are you sure want to delete ?');" />
```

OnClientClick : Gets or sets the client-side script that executes when a Button control's Click event is raised.

OnClick  : Raises the Click event of the Button control

So in your case the **confirm** it should raise a client-side script. So you should give in a OnClientClick  event .

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in the OnClientClick

e.g.,

```
btnMainDelete.OnClientClick = "if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') == false) return false;";
```

Answer (score 0):

using this

```
btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Do you really want to delete this item?'
```

This will delete forever item in your database!');");